# TensorFlow, "'module' object has no attribute 'placeholder'"

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've been trying to use tensorflow for two days now installing and reinstalling it over and over again in python2.7 and 3.4.  No matter what I do, I get this error message when trying to use tensorflow.placeholder()

It's very boilerplate code:

```
tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
```

No matter what I do I always get the trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/willim/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/willim/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tensorflow.py", line 53, in <module>
    tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: By any chance, do you have another file names `tensorflow.py` where you work?

Comment: This will help better.
https://www.datasciencelearner.com/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-placeholder/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It happened to me too. I had tensorflow and it was working pretty well, but when I install tensorflow-gpu along side the previous tensorflow this error arose then I did these 3 steps and it started working with no problem:

1. I removed tensorflow-gpu, tensorflow, tensorflow-base packages from Anaconda. Using.

`conda remove tensorflow-gpu tensorflow tensorflow-base`

2. re-installed tensorflow. Using

`conda install tensorflow`

Comment: awesome man! solved my problem!! didn't expect that it's caused by conda

Comment: Great! It was helpful

Comment: Thank you so much, but i am not able to use GPU even after installed "Tensorflow-gpu 1.2.1-Py36cuda8.0cudnn6.0_0". keep on executing with CPU not with GPU. If i specify with tf.device('/gpu:0') then i got exception saying you have only CPU device.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last step should be conda install tensorflow-gpu, otherwise you are stuck with cpu (only mention cause the comment before me).

Answer (score 192):

If you have this error after an upgrade to TensorFlow 2.0, you can still use 1.X API by replacing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

by

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Comment: thats exactly what i did and i am getting this error

Comment: That worked for me for 'placeholder', but failed once I got to 'contrib' in the tutorial I was trying to follow.  Guess I need to try to find a tutorial that uses v2.

Comment: Didn't work! Perhaps it works only for `tensorflow`? not for `tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: This should be marked as accepted solution

Comment: @Joe for `contrib` you should downgrade to tf1 or instead of contrib and downgrading to tf1, searching for similar named function in tf2's compat v1 and changing function is better.

Comment: https://www.datasciencelearner.com/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-placeholder/

Answer (score 43):

**Solution: Do not use "tensorflow" as your filename.**

Notice that you use tensorflow.py as your filename. And I guess you write code like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Then you are actually importing the script file "tensorflow.py" that is under your current working directory, rather than the "real" tensorflow module from Google.

Here is the order in which a module will be searched when importing:

> 1. The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> 2. PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names,
>      with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> 3. The installation-dependent default.

Comment: Related: I had an issue (tensorflow 0.9), in that scripts stopped working: " AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'constant' ". Thanks to this answer, I looked and noticed that I had a folder named "tensorflow". I renamed that folder, and my scripts are working again.

Comment: very useful, it saves my life!

Comment: super useful :D

Comment: so how should you import it instead?

Comment: You are not showing the solution, you are explaining the reason for the error

Comment: @Sherzod I thought I have shown the solution (in bold) is: **Do not use "tensorflow" as your filename.**

Answer (score 35):

Instead of `tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 2], dtype=tf.float32)` use something like
`tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=[None, 2], dtype=tf.float32)` if you don't want to disable v2 completely.

Comment: it's better than the others

Answer (score 23):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

works.
I am using Python 3.7 and tensorflow 2.0.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that .placeholder() , .reset_default_graph() , and others were removed with version 2.  I ran into this issue using Docker image: `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3` which automatically pulls the latest version.  I was working in 1.13.1 and was 'upgraded to 2' automatically and started getting the error messages.  I fixed this by being more specific with my image: `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.1-gpu-py3`.

More info can be found here:  https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/effective_tf2

Answer (score 11):

Avoid using the below striked out statement in tensorflow=2.0

i̶m̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ ̶t̶e̶n̶s̶o̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶f̶ ̶x̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶f̶.̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶h̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶(̶s̶h̶a̶p̶e̶=̶[̶N̶o̶n̶e̶,̶ ̶2̶]̶,̶ ̶d̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶t̶f̶.̶f̶l̶o̶a̶t̶3̶2̶)̶

**You can disable the v2 behavior by using the following code**

This one is perfectly working for me.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: MAGIC just happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I also got the same error. May be because of the version of tensorflow. 
After installing tensorflow 1.4.0, I got relief from the error.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.4.0
```

Comment: tensrflow 13.0.1 did it. (older ones are removed from pip)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using TensorFlow 2.0, then some code developed for tf 1.x may not code work. Either you can follow the link : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

or you can install a previous version of tf by
pip3 install tensorflow==version

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look at the [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

These codes:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
```

need to be migrated in TensorFlow 2 as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as v1
tf_in = vi.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the old version of tensorflow instead of the new version

[https://inneka.com/ml/tf/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-placeholder/][1]

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the keras model with tensorflow 2, as here

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import  Input, Embedding, Dot, Reshape, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent version 2.0 does not support placeholder. 
I uninstalled 2.0 using command: `conda remove tensorflow`.
then I installed 1.15.0 using command: `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.15.0`.
1.15 is latest in version 1 series. You can change as per you wish and requirement.
For seeing all version, use command: `conda search tensorflow`.
It worked for Anaconda3 in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

or this (if you have GPU):

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue on Ubuntu 16LTS when tensor flow was installed over existing python installation.

Workaround:
1.)Uninstall tensorflow from pip and pip3

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

2.)Uninstall python & python3

```
sudo apt-get remove python-dev python3-dev python-pip python3-pip
```

3.)Install only a single version of  python(I used python 3)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
```

4.)Install tensorflow to python3

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

for non GPU tensorflow, run this command

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

for GPU tensorflow, run below command

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Suggest not to install GPU and vanilla version of tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

**If you get this on tensorflow 2.0.0+**, it's very likely because the code isn't compatible with the newer version of tensorflow.

To fix this, run the `tf_upgrade_v2` [script](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade).

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --infile=YOUR_SCRIPT.py --outfile=YOUR_SCRIPT.py
```

Answer (score 1):

The error shows up because we are using tensorflow version 2 and the command is from version 1. So if we use:

```
tf.compat.v1.summary.(method_name)
```

It'll work

Answer (score 0):

Because you cant use placeholder in tensflow2.0version, so you need to use tensflow1*, or you need to change your code to fix tensflow2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before after tried to upgrade tensorflow, I solved it by reinstalling Tensorflow and Keras.

`pip uninstall tensorflow`

`pip uninstall keras`

Then:

`pip install tensorflow`

`pip install keras`

Answer (score 0):

There have been many suggestions and some of them did work. But I would rather convert v1 tf project to v2 project for better maintenance. I am surprised no one suggested it here:

```
$tf_upgrade_v2 \
--intree my_project/ \
--outtree my_project_v2/ \
--reportfile report.txt
```

I copied pasted from this stack overflow answer: [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)

You do need to inspect the report.txt and make sure it does what you would expect.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with TensorFlow version; the one you are running is `2.0` or something above `1.5`, while `placeholder` can only work with `1.4`.

So simply uninstall TensorFlow, then install it again with version 1.4 and everything will work.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to use TensorFlow 2.x syntax with TensorFlow 1.x. The error message you're encountering indicates that TensorFlow 2.13 doesn't have a 'placeholder' attribute.

In TensorFlow 2.x, you should use the tf.Variable or tf.constant for creating tensors with specific values, and placeholders are not used anymore. Instead, you can use regular Python variables.

Here's how you can modify your code to work with TensorFlow 2.x:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_in = tf.Variable( [None, A], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score -4):

It may be the typo if you incorrectly wrote the `placeholder` word.
In my case I misspelled it as `placehoder` and got the error like this:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'placehoder'`