# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow version 1.3.0 and Tensorboard (0.1.8), and when I am using `tf.placeholder()`, `tf.GLOBAL_VARIABLES()` or `tf.global_variables_initializer`, it get an error like the one in the title. I know that there is an update in the function's syntax for this version, but I can't find what is wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide more information? (snippet of code, more lines of the traceback). Also, this may or may not be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386150/8581827