# How to switch from the old to the new version of TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I did not use TensorFlow for a while and now, when I was starting to use it again, I have the problem with the first basic line of my code:

```
X = tf.placeholder(name = 'X')
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

What I got from googling a bit, is that the `placeholder` method got deprecated.

So, my question is where should I start reading to figure out what was deprecated and what is the new way to use TensorFlow?

Comment: A quick Google search points to this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: I do not want to migrate my code.

Comment: [This page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) says that one should "use `tf.keras.Input` to replace `tf.compat.v1.placeholder`", if you're looking for the "new way" of using TensorFlow

Comment: But this is only about placeholders. I guess there many other changes as well. Is there a systematic, comprehensive overview of all the changes?

Comment: What about [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/tf1_vs_tf2) ?

Comment: ok, this looks very relevant. Thanks.

Comment: You should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383812/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can still access your older `TF 1.x` code by selecting `Tensorflow 1.x`  before running your code:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'X')
X
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor 'X_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>
```

[tf.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) is replaced by [tf.keras.Input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) in tensorflow eager execution mode (later version of TensorFlow 2.0).

Please check this [Migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for detailed understanding of converting `TF 1.x` code to `TF 2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scripts, Answer by @TFer2 will not work. You need to disable tfv2 behaviour, so that you can use the v1 behaviour.

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Now you can use tf v1 things.

I would suggest seeing some examples for tfv1 vs tfv2 tasks. These will help you understanding the major differences.

For example binary classification in tf1 vs binary classification in tf2.